# 2.80 Make the data single user. Like pressing U key in blender 2.79

Tags: mesh, shortcut

In 2.79 I could press <kbd>U</kbd> to make data single user.  How can I do this in 2.80, what is the hotkey?

Answer (score 5):

From menu `Object` - `Relations` - `Make single user`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do restore the functionality to a hotkey is to add a custom keymap in Preferences. I added one under 3D View > 3D View (Global) with `object.make_single_user` as the function and *Selected Objects* for Type.

[image]

It seemed to work ok, but it doesn't bring up the context menu like before. The options appear in the small window at the bottom of the screen, usually collapsed by default. Or if you always want to perform the action on data, I think you can pre-check that Object Data box in the keymap settings and bypass the context box entirely.

**If you want to keep the modal context menu with a hotkey though**, you can right-click the *Make Single User* menu item (under Object > Relations) and add it to your Quick Favorites menu (Q).

[image]