# Deleting object from group with links

Tags: modeling, linked-data

I linked objects with Ctrl+L. How can I now unlink a single object from the group with links? It used to be "U" in version before 2.8, I guess.

Comment: You want to make the object single user ?

Comment: I want to unlink the object.

Comment: In that case, could you specify that in your question ? You asked about deleting the object which is not the same as unlinking it, which is not the same as making it single user. If you don't know what the difference is between these terms, I suggest looking them up, this will help you get the exact answer you are looking for. Cheers

Comment: Specified. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it can be called "making the object single user" and here is the answer:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134264/2-80-make-the-data-single-user-like-pressing-u-key-in-blender-2-79
Thanks to Gorgious.

Comment: Glad it helped !